# How to set MIME type of application/vnd.apple.pkpass in order to share pass by link or email

Tags: ios, mime-types, passbook

I just created an app and a pass, so I can add the pass to the PassBook in iPod, but I cannot share the pass by email or link from web server. From the documentation I read from Apple, I need to add a MIME type as `application/vnd.apple.pkpass`. However, I don't understand clearly what steps should I do. I don't know how to use MIME type.

How should I add this MIME type in order to use pass from my web service?

Comment: What server are you using (Apache, nginx, IIS?)  What language are you using (PHP, C#?)

Comment: Server is Apache and I use PHP language.

Comment: Which of the solutions below did you try?

Comment: what are the differences between using pure php solution and simple php ?

Comment: No practical difference.  The PHP solution I gave doesn't require any server configuration and will always force the file to download.  It also prevents the browser from caching the file.  You can accomplish the same by configuring Apache.  It also adds a `Last-Modified` header, which is used by the iOS device when requesting an updated .pkpass bundle.  The 'simple' PHP solution of just adding a `Content-Type` header may not be sufficient to ensure that a .pkpass file downloads each and every time.

Comment: your solution works well !

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Apache**

Add the following line to either:

- the `.htaccess` in the directory serving your .pkpass, or
- to the `mime.types` file, or
- to your appache `httpd.conf` or virtuatl server `.conf` file

Then restart Apache (not required if adding to `.htaccess`)

```
AddType application/vnd.apple.pkpass    pkpass
```

---

**nginx**

Add the following line to your `mime.types` file and restart nginx

```
application/vnd.apple.pkpass    pkpass;
```

---

**IIS**

1. Open IIS Manager and navigate to the level you want to manage.
2. In Features View, double-click MIME Types.
3. In the Actions pane, click Add.
4. In the Add MIME Type `.pkpass`
5. Type `application.vnd.pkpass` n the MIME text box
6. Click OK
7. Restart IIS

---

If you are serving your file via a script and are not able to edit your web server config you could add the following line before any content is sent:

**PHP**

```
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.apple.pkpass');
```

**C#**

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/vnd.apple.pkpass");
```

Comment: I did like you wrote above already and this is content of my php file: <?php 
header('Content-type: application/vnd.apple.pkpass');

 echo "<a href= 'GenericMemberCard.pkpass'> Click me to add pass</a>";

?> is it like this for testing ?

Comment: See my alternative answer for a pure PHP solution

Answer (score 4):

For a pure PHP solution, add your .pkpass bundle to the server, then create the following file and name this file pass.php.

```
<?php   
$pkpass_file = '/path/to/your/.pkpass/file/GenericMemberCard.pkpass';

header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Content-Type: application/vnd.apple.pkpass");
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="pass.pkpass"');
clearstatcache();
$filesize = filesize($pkpass_file);
if ($filesize)
    header("Content-Length: ". $filesize);
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
if (filemtime($pkpass_file)) {
    date_default_timezone_set("UTC");
    header('Last-Modified: ' . date("D, d M Y H:i:s", filemtime($pkpass_file)) . ' GMT');
}
flush();
readfile($pkpass_file);
```

Then create a second file linking to the file you created above.

```
<a href="pass.php">Click to download your pass</a>
```

Comment: I am trying the exact same thing but for some reason it always show "safari can not download" in my iphone 4s and 6. It would be great if you can help me with this - I have been trying this since last 1 day and I have an urgent requirement.

Comment: Most likely your signature file is incorrect, but it could also be a problem with your pass.json.  Turn on Additional Passbook logging from your phone's developer menu, attach your phone to Xcode and review the console output as you attempt to load the pass.  This should give you some insight into what is going wrong.

Answer (score 2):

I have implemented this using an express server.
When I am generating a pass, and want to send it over via an URL, I set the headers as follows -

```
router.get("/getpass", (req, res) => {
     const passData = getPass();
     res.setHeader("Content-type", application/vnd.apple.pkpas);
     res.setHeader(
              "Content-disposition",
              `attachment; filename=generatedPass.pkpass`,
            );
     res.status(201).send(passData);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Through Windows 10
IIS

1. Open IIS Manager and navigate to the level you want to manage.
2. In Features View, double-click MIME Types.
3. In the Actions pane, click Add.
4. In the Add MIME Type `.pkpass`
5. Type `application.vnd.pkpass` n the MIME text box
6. Click OK
7. Restart IIS

Answer (score 0):

Any one still struggling with IIS.  For IIS the suggest types here are wrong IIS expects xx/xxxxxx so this is what the correct one would look like in IIS.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If anyone every got to this page and was stuck like I was trying to use axios to download an apple pass via the web using responseType: 'blob'

I tried all the usual ideas about Mimetype etc but in the end what solved it was using 'arraybuffer' instead of 'blob'

```
            try {
                const response = await axios.get(this.route('api.apple.pass'), {
                    responseType: 'arraybuffer', //instead of blob
                });
                const data = new Uint8Array(response.data);
                const dataUri = 'data:application/vnd.apple.pkpass;base64,' + btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, data));
                const link = document.createElement('a');
                link.href = dataUri;
                link.download = 'pass.pkpass';
                link.click();
               } catch (error) {
                console.error('Error downloading pass:', error);
              }
           }
```