# Why last updated(null)

Tags: web-services, ios6, passbook

I created a pass and can register device to my server. I also updated this pass by changing some contents and insert a new row of pass to pass table. But why in console, last updated (null) ? this is what I get from console: 
`Apr  6 10:30:29 CamMobs-iPod4 passd[21] <Warning>: Get serial #s task (for device b6511c0dd47d04da449ce427b27fea74, pass type pass.cam-mob.passbookpasstest, last updated (null);`  `with web service url http://192.168.1.202:8888/passesWebserver/) got response with code 200`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever a .pkpass bundle is accepted or replaced in a device's Passbook library, Passbook will tag the pass with a last updated attribute.

This attribute is typically set by the `Last-Modified` header a webserver sends the first time the pass is downloaded, and your web service sends with every response to the "[Get Latest Version of a Pass](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/PassKit/Reference/PassKit_WebService/WebService.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011988)" response.

Passbook also polls your web service using a "[Getting the Serial Numbers for Passes Associated with a Device](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/PassKit/Reference/PassKit_WebService/WebService.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011988)" method for `serialNumbers`, using the `deviceLibraryIdentifier` and `passTypeIdentifier` as criteria.

The "[Getting the Serial Numbers for Passes Associated with a Device](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/PassKit/Reference/PassKit_WebService/WebService.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011988)" response should contain a tag `lastUpdated`, indicating when the results of this query were last changed (I.e. when was the last time that a pass using the `passTypeIdentifier` registered to this `deviceLibraryIdentifier` was last updated).

However, the very first time Passbook sends a "[Getting the Serial Numbers for Passes Associated with a Device](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/PassKit/Reference/PassKit_WebService/WebService.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011988)", it will not have received a `lastUpdated` tag which is why it is showing `null` in your console log.  Also, sending a `lastUpdated` tag is optional, so if it is not present, or if it is not sent correctly, then you will always see `last updated (null)` for this request.

You are free to use whatever you like as a `lastUpdated` tag.  The simplest solution to implement is a unix timestamp as there is no need to mess around with date formats.

Comment: So I need to make response for 'Getting the Serial Numbers for Passes Associated with a Device'and 'Getting the Latest Version of a Pass' before Opening a connection to the Apple Push Notification Service (APNS) ?

Comment: Yes - you need to implement every method of the web service.  You can test the 'Getting the Latest version of a Pass' method by flipping the pass over and pulling down on the back to manually trigger a refresh

Comment: for getting the Serial Numbers for Passes Associated with a Device,
I use this header:  header('Last-Modified: ' . date("D, d M Y H:i:s", filemtime('/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/passesWebserver/DigiClubCard.pkpass')) . ' GMT+07:00');
why last updated is still null ?

Comment: The lastUpdated tag is set by the lastUpdated tag that you sent in the last JSON response to the "Getting the Serial Numbers for Passes Associated with a Device" request.  If you have never sent a valid response to this method then lastUpdated will always be null.  Passbook does not use the `LAst-Modified` header for this call - if only uses it when you are sending .pkpass files.

Comment: how to send .pkpass file to device ?

Comment: When - initially, or in response to the "Getting the Serial Numbers for Passes Associated with a Device" method?  The answer in both cases is to set a header and then server the .pkpass bundle, which was answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15383552/how-to-set-mime-type-of-application-vnd-apple-pkpass-in-order-to-share-pass-by-l

Comment: now I get 'Apr  8 10:59:03 CamMobs-iPod4 passd[21] <Warning>: Get serial numbers task completed with update tag 1365393543, serial numbers (
     0001
 )
'

Comment: I have response in getting the Serial Numbers for Passes Associated with a Device, but no response yet in getting the Latest Version of a Pass !

Comment: Great! That is exactly what you want to see.  When the device next calls that method (most likely in response to a push request), you will see the lastUpdated tag 1365393543

Comment: yes ! In pass table, I insert new row of pass and I only change 1 content and UpdateTag. What I need to do next is response for getting the latest version of pass !

Comment: so I need to add : header('Content-Type: application/vnd.apple.pkpass');
 and how can I send newUpdated .pkpass to device ?

Comment: so I need to use this : <?php   
$pkpass_file = '/path/to/your/.pkpass/file/GenericMemberCard.pkpass';

header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Content-Type: application/vnd.apple.pkpass");
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="pass.pkpass"');

Comment: $filesize = filesize($pkpass_file);
if ($filesize)
    header("Content-Length: ". $filesize);
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
if (filemtime($pkpass_file)) {
    date_default_timezone_set("UTC");
    header('Last-Modified: ' . date("D, d M Y H:i:s", filemtime($pkpass_file)) . ' GMT');
}
flush();
readfile($pkpass_file);

Comment: can the old pass updates automatically or need a push notification ?

Comment: It needs a push notification - otherwise, how will it know that it needs to update?  The user can also manually update it by flipping the pass and pulling down.

Comment: So now it's time for me to connect to APNS !