# sending PKPAss to Safari with PHP

Tags: xcode, swift, passbook, passkit

All,

I am following a tutorial to get PHP to deliver a pass. I have been using the console to check the logs in XCODE. I have also checked and there is no PHP errors on the local server.

When I browse to the page which should download the pass, I get this on my safari screen on my iPhone.

[image]

So it is downloading from the local server, but I cannot see the pass, just the binary code.. Is there anything on iPhone 6/ iOS 8 that I should be checking ?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your web server is not correctly set up to serve the file with a MIME type that identifies the .pkpass file as a Passbook pass.  More so, your server appears to be using a text or html MIME type that instructs the browser to read the file as text.

See my answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15383552/how-to-set-mime-type-of-application-vnd-apple-pkpass-in-order-to-share-pass-by-l) for how to properly configure your server.