# Apple PassKit Wallet download link on website

Tags: ios, wallet, passkit

I have already created an Apple coupon `discountcoupon.pkpass`. I uploaded it on my public server and I gave direct download link. When I open that link in my iPhone or iPad, iOS doesn't recognize the pass.

How can I give download link on my website?
When the user click in my coupon link, it should show the Wallet add pass screen.

Comment: Do not add the Apple tag. Read the tag's description.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the MIME type to `application/vnd.apple.pkpass` for iOS to recognise the file as a pass and to open Wallet.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15383552/how-to-set-mime-type-of-application-vnd-apple-pkpass-in-order-to-share-pass-by-l) for how to do that.

Comment: this stopped working on iOS 17, any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Inside the folder where you have your index.html with the download link to the coupon, create a new .htaccess file with this line of code inside:

```
AddType application/vnd.apple.pkpass    pkpass
```

then save it and refresh and it will work

Answer (score -1):

Do you have a mac? Try to open the `.pkpass` file in iOS simulator and read the system log.

You need to understand .`pkpass` just a "zip file". Although you can zip as a `.pkpass` file, the content of that passes may not fulfill the requirements of iPhone setting, such cert not valid or `pass.json` something wrong.

So, try to use iOS simulator and log the error message, it take a easy way for your coming up development

Comment: I.pkpass working great when I email or iMessage my question was when I'm trying to auto detect iPhone it's downloading in iPhone but when it's downloading it's shows message in what app u want to open this file. But when I send email or iMessage it shows wallet icon and directly open in wallet and shows add link.

Comment: @M.A Sorry for my mistake.Try to create a new webpage for download .pkpass, try to use "application/vnd.apple.pkpass"  as a HTTP Content Type and header value to be "attachment"