# pkpass file open in Safari Mac but not on iPhone

Tags: ios, wallet, pkpass

I created a pass successfully and it opens properly on my MacBook safari browser however, when I try to open it on my physical iPhone or the Simulator it looks like safari doesn't recognize the pass file.

On Mac Safari it shows this:
[Snapshot of how the pass looks when I download it on Mac Safari](https://i.stack.imgur.com/736gE.png)

On iPhone or Simulator Safari it shows this:
[Sanpshot of how it look on iPhone or Simulator Safari](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aGzPp.png)

I've checked that all image assets are included in the bundle as well as using the right mime type(application/vnd.apple.pkpass) which I even added to my server mime.types conf file.

Any other thing to check in order to fix this strange issue.

Request and response headers:

```
URL: http://hayak.localhost/api/request/pass?locale=en-us&uuid=eb5b16db-2a33-4bc8-b3e6-b5dcc5240dfd
```

```
Request GET /api/request/pass HTTP/1.1 
Accept: */* 
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-us 
Host: hayak.localhost 
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_6) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/14.0.2 Safari/605.1.15 Connection: keep-alive Referer: http://hayak.localhost/request/vw
```

```
Response HTTP/1.1 200 OK 
Content-Type: application/vnd.apple.pkpass
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100 
Pragma: no-cache 
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=CP_3_731585792.pkpass
Last-Modified: Tue, 02 Feb 2021 16:00:53 GMT
Cache-Control: public 
Date: Wed, 03 Feb 2021 15:18:46 GMT 
Content-Length: 302319 
Connection: Keep-Alive 
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Vary: Authorization 
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.4.12 Server: Apache/2.4.46 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.2u PHP/7.4.12 mod_wsgi/3.5 Python/2.7.13 mod_fastcgi/mod_fastcgi-SNAP-0910052141 mod_perl/2.0.11 Perl/v5.30.1 Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary X-RateLimit-Limit: 60 X-RateLimit-Remaining: 52 Content-Description: File Transfer
```

JS (Vue) Code:

```
methods: 
    {
        forceFileDownload(response){
          const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data]))
          const link = document.createElement('a')
          link.href = url
          link.setAttribute('download', 'pass.pkpass') //or any other extension
          document.body.appendChild(link)
          link.click()
        },
        downloadWithAxios(){
        axios({
          method: 'get',
          url: '/request/pass',
          params: {locale: this.$i18n.locale, uuid: this.$store.state.app.request.uuid},
          responseType: 'arraybuffer'
        })
        .then(response => {
          
          this.forceFileDownload(response)
          
        })
        .catch(() => console.log('error occured'))
      }  
    }
```

PHP code:

```
$path = storage_path().'/passgenerator/'.$pass_identifier.'.pkpass';
        
        return response()->download($path, $pass_identifier.'.pkpass', 
        [
          'Content-Transfer-Encoding' => 'binary',
          'Content-Description' => 'File Transfer',
          'Content-Disposition' => 'attachment; filename=pass.pkpass',
          'Content-length' => strlen($pkpass),
          'Content-Type' => PassGenerator::getPassMimeType(),
          'Pragma' => 'no-cache',
        ]);
```

Comment: Does it download on a device? Can you post a link to the pass so that we can replicate? Could you post `curl -I https://{pass url.pkpass}`

Comment: Yes it downloads fine with same expected size (similar to the file size on Mac).

Comment: Unfortunately, I can’t put a link yet because I’m still doing this locally.

Comment: Can you paste the headers using curl?

Comment: didn't know how to get the header from curl but I tried to copy it from safari console.
sorry for the late response as I was far from my computer all day.

See below.

Comment: Try changing your endpoint to add a `.pkpass` extension. E.g. ` http://hayak.localhost/api/request/pass.pkpass?locale=en-us&uuid=eb5b16db-2a33-4bc8-b3e6-b5dcc5240dfd .
If you are accessing via Javascript, you will need to make sure you have the proper Access-Control headers set.  You should change your Cache-Control header, to `Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0`. And consider adding `Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary`.

Comment: can you please clarify what do you mean by "changing your endpoint".

Comment: Change `/pass?` to `/pass.pkpass?`

Comment: See the question post above, I added front and back end codes.

Comment: I tried changing the endpoint to 'pass.pkpass' but that didn't have any impact. still having the same response on iPhone/Simulator Safari.

Comment: See the last answer to this question for PHP headers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15383552/how-to-set-mime-type-of-application-vnd-apple-pkpass-in-order-to-share-pass-by-l.  And remove 'Content-Description: File Transfer'.

Comment: Tried changing the header as advised but still I'm getting the same response on iPhone Safari.

Answer (score 0):

Since you do not get the file directly from server URL, but through `axios` then construct the file again, therefore setting these things in PHP will not help:

```
'Content-Transfer-Encoding' => 'binary',
'Content-Description' => 'File Transfer',
'Content-Disposition' => 'attachment; filename=pass.pkpass',
'Content-length' => strlen($pkpass),
'Content-Type' => PassGenerator::getPassMimeType(),
```

You could remove them if you want, because we only need the buffer data.

The problem is when you construct the file again in frontend, you must provide MINE type `application/vnd.apple.pkpass` for it, it will help Safari recognize the `pkpass` file and open it automatically.

So, replace this line:

```
const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data]))
```

with this may help:

```
const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(
  new Blob([response.data], {
    type: "application/vnd.apple.pkpass",
  })
);
```